# How do I configure a location block to always return a single file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

In my application I want the location "/" to return a static index.html file, I want "/static" to serve static files from a folder and I want all other requests to return 404 NOT FOUND. At a later point I'm going to redirect all other requests to a WSGI server.

This is currently my configuration:

```
# Dev server.
server {
    listen 1337;
    charset UTF-8;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ static/index_debug.html break;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/tomas/projects/streamcore/static;
    }
}
```

The static folder is working perfectly, but "/" is returning 404 NOT FOUND. I have also tried:

```
alias /home/tomas/projects/streamcore/static/index_debug.html;
```

In the location block, but that returns 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. It seems like `alias` doesn't like single files. Additionally I've tried:

```
try_files static/index_debug.html;
```

But that stops the server from starting with the error "invalid number of arguments in try_files directive". Apparently `try_files` actually requires you to try more than one file, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for.

So my question is: **How so I configure a location block to always return a static file?**

---

**EDIT:** I've seen from other answers that `alias` should indeed accept a single file as argument, so I tried:

```
location = / {
    alias /home/tomas/projects/streamcore/static/index_debug.html;
}
```

But I still only get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. The error log for the "/" request says:

```
[alert] 28112#0: *7 "/home/tomas/projects/streamcore/static/index_debug.htmlindex.html" is not a directory
```

Why is it trying to open "index_debug.htmlindex.html"? I'm not using the `index` directive anywhere.

Comment: Can you `try_files static/index_debug.html static/index_debug.html;`

Comment: @ceejayoz: Trying your suggestion with `location =/` I get 404 NOT FOUND, with `location /` I get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you're missing the Index directive... Any webserver will always look for the index file, providing the root URI (/), i think you can override this by adding: `location / { return 404; }`

Comment: @MartinoDino: Why do I need it? And where?

Comment: `location = / {Index /home/tomas/projects/streamcore/static/index_debug.html;}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just tested this and it works for me:

```
server {
    root /tmp/root;
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location /static {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
        location / {
            rewrite ^ /static/index_debug.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

The file `/tmp/root/static/index_debug.html` exists of course :)

I can hit any URL and I just get the static page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try_files` and use an HTTP code, e.g. 404, as the second argument:

```
try_files /static/index_debug.html =404;
```

Note the leading slash.

The complete example would look like this (you don't need the rewrite):

```
# Dev server.
server {
    listen 1337;
    charset UTF-8;
    root /home/tomas/projects/streamcore/;

    location / {
        try_files /static/index_debug.html =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try_files and a redirect to a named location with rewrite. Like this:

```
server {
    root /tmp/root;
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @index;
        }

        location @index {
            rewrite ^ static/index_debug.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

If file exists in `/tmp/root` it will be served, otherwise uri will be rewritten to `static/index_debug.html` and it will be served.